# How can i stop sending messages which are sending in loop on click of an button in android

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I want to know how can I stop message sending in a loop.
When I press stop, messages are still sent.
I have provided a `stop()` method.

```
for (i = 0; i < copy; i++) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(stop!=1)
                            sms.sendTextMessage(number,null,message,sentPIn,pdelint);
                    }

                }, 25000);


stop method

int stop=0;

public void st(View view){
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b.setText("Stopped");
    stop=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify St function to this

```
public void st() {
     Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
     @Override
     b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           b.setText("Stopped!");
           stop=1;
     });
}
```

The problem was u were not using an listener to detect button press. It is not advisable to change the button text use a text view instead!

Comment: I think he has declared st() in his xml.

Comment: @Kunu What? that's a program he dint declare it in XML!

Comment: i have set onclick method st in xml for button

Answer (score 0):

Most likely he has set `onClick` attribute in the xml, although only he'll be able to clarify that.

I'm saying that because I see View as a parameter in the method `st(View v)`.

Although if the attribute onClick is not set in xml @Audi 's solution would be good. Though on the contrary if the attribute has been set in the xml then
you should check if `view.getId() == R.id.button` then apply a button cast to your view and set its text to "Stopped".

Comment: actually button works good. this code does not give delay of 25 second to send next message.I want to know how can i delay every message 25 second and stop sending message on click of stop button?